# Redirect sed output to stdin

Tags: bash

I have a file which I currently send as an email like so

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail me@gmail.com < f1.txt
```

I made some changes to the file so that it includes a placeholder which I adjust using sed like so

```
sed -e s/PLACEHOLDER/TEST/g f1.txt
```

How can I combine the 2? I thought it would be done like

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail me@gmail.com <(sed -e s/PLACEHOLDER/TEST/g f1.txt)
```

But that 'hangs'. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Learn about *pipes*.

Comment: To be fair, a process substitution *is* (basically) a pipe, under the hood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've almost got it.

Your command line was:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail me@gmail.com <(sed -e s/PLACEHOLDER/TEST/g f1.txt)
```

You're using *[Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)* to turn the sed command inside the `<( .. )` construct into a temporary file handle which will be read by sendmail. Unfortunately, you're not actually redirecting in from that temporary file handle.

The fix should simply be to add a `<` before the command substitution:

```
/usr/sbin/sendmail me@example.com < <(sed -e 's/PLACEHOLDER/TEST/g' f1.txt)
                                  ↑
```

That said, it might be preferable to use PIPES instead, so as to avoid the dependency on bash:

```
sed -e 's/PLACEHOLDER/TEST/g' f1.txt | /usr/sbin/sendmail me@example.com
```

The eventual effect is the same, but the process is a little simpler, and is portable to POSIX shell interpreters which do not support process substitution.